# Suppose that $1+2+...+n=\overline{aaa}$. Which of the following items CERTAINLY divides $n$? $5,6,7,8,11$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, summation, integers

> Suppose that $1+2+...+n=\overline{aaa}$. Which of the following items CERTAINLY divides $n$?
>      $5,6,7,8,11$

I converted the given relation into the following:
  $$n(n+1)=2*3*37*a$$
Now I think we must consider all different cases of divisibility but can't give reasoning...

Comment: What exactly, is meant by $\overline{aaa}$?

Comment: A 3-digit number

Comment: Like $111 \times a$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From you equality you can get that $n=37$ or $n+1=37$ because

even if $n+1=74$ you can not get the number $100a+10a+a$, where $a\in\{1,...,9\}$.

Comment: Yes,it's clearly seen.But what about the given choices?

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi The case $n=37$ does not help, but the case $n+1=37$ gives number $6$.

Comment: Can we say it decisively?!

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi No, of course. There is only a possibility that $6$ divides $n$,

Comment: If $n=37$, then non of the given choices is acceptable,so $n+1=37$.Now the answer is CERTAINLY 6.Thank you.

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi You are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

$100a+10a+a=n(n+1)/2$
$\implies n^2+n=222a$
$\implies a(n/a)^2+(n/a)=222$
$\implies 2n=-1+\sqrt{1+888a}$
(Negative sqrt is rejected)
As $n$ is a natural number, so is $2n$.
The quantity under the radical must be a perfect square and its square root must be greater than 1.

Again, as $a \in \left\{1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9\right\}$
The quantity $\sqrt{1+888a}$ is a positive integer only for $a=6$.
This gives $n=36$

Hence, among the choices given, $6$ perfectly divides $n$